# gcc -l option and .la library files

Tags: c++, gcc, shared

Could you please explain, how linking with -l option against .la files works?

As far as my experience reaches - i have only linked against static library (.a) files.

Now i took a look at some Qt generated Makefiles and cant figure out, how linker figures out to use/open libQtCore.la file, when -l QtCore switch is specified, instead of looking for libQtCore.a.

Also - gcc manual states, that -l[library name] switch will include lib[library name].a, not lib[libraryname].la.

Comment: I'm not familiar with the extension `.la`. What does `file yourfile.la` say? Maybe it's just the same as an object archive and can be renamed to `.a`

Answer (score 16):

`.la` files are as far as I know libtool junk and shouldn't be linked to manually. They are used internally by libtool for whatever reason it needs them. You should link to the `*.a` file. In a Qt install/build there should be `*.a` files to link to.

Comment: how to compile with .la in order to create static library e.g example.la

Comment: @Muhammad As I said, `*.la` files are junk. They are not static libraries. Open one up, you'll see it's a bunch of text. You want the `*.a` files.